# c# undefined amount of object for data type (like params[])

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, parameters

Let's assume I have a sqlite database. That database has a table called main with 5 columns (id, c1, c2, c3, c4).

Client calls executeQuery which looks like this:

```
    public Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, string, string, string>> executeSql(string statement) {
        var ret = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, string, string, string>>;
        var dbcmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        for(int i = 0; i < Entries; i++) {
            dbcmd.CommandText = statement.Replace("i", i.ToString());
            var reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader(); 
            //.... Evalulate query....
            ret.Add(); //add to Dic
        }
    }
```

I have no idea how many columns the client is asking for in his statement. Is there any type that allows me to work properly in such a scenario. What I want is sth like this:

```
 Dictionary<int, Tuple<params[] string>>
```

which would provide me with a variable amount of strings to be added into the Tuple.

If there is nothing like that is there any clean way to solve this instead of using an array that will have empty entries (as it will break loops and is pretty terrible to read and mantain) nor do I want to have to use 90% of the same code just for every single case (aka executeSqlOne(), executeSqlTwo() etc...) as it would bloat the code heavily.

Comment: Can you give some examples of different statements? I guess Entries is the number of column the client asks for? Is your table structure changeable? what if you would change the table to id, parameter number, value? By this you will retrieve a value for each id-parameter combination, the sql would always look the same and you can add the result to your `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`

Comment: Yes Dictionary<int, List<String>> solves everything. I am going to hava rest now my mind is appearently over worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, instead of `Tuple<string, string, string, string>` you can use `List<string>` I believe and you will not have to worry about no.of columns. Just add the resultant columns to the list and return the same.

Comment: Wow I should really get a break. Yes obviously you are completely right.